# Workaround for NODE_ENV during build

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, cloudcontrol

I'm having a problem with a NPM post-install script, the issue is that the build process ignores the configured NODE_ENV (set via `cctrlapp x/y config.add`) and always defaults to `production`. For what I've seen this was "resolved" [two months ago by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/416). From [this issue](https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt/issues/17), it seems that it should be transparent.

Is there something I must do to have access to my ENV variables during the build? Any workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround, from the different ENV vars the only one with a value during the build is `DEP_NAME`, but it's enough since we can extract the `env` from it: `project/environment`. This works in CloudControl, no idea if it would work in Heroku.

```
if ('DEP_NAME' in process.env) {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.DEP_NAME.split('/')[1];
}
```

Comment: The 'DEP_NAME' is indeed available. We also provide a special environment variable to determine if the buildpack is running. It's called 'BUILDPACK_RUNNING'.